# Check if Flutter widget will/can get focus

Tags: flutter, widget, focus, uinavigationbar

In Flutter's focus system you can specify what should happen after *FocusNode.unfocus* is called. When I use ***previouslyFocusedChild*** it will automatically give focus to the previously focused child.

I was wondering if it is possible to get this information from a child perspective. For example: I would like to highlight the previsouslyFocusedChild to give the end-user some indication which element in the UI will get focus after performing an action. Is this possible?